# How to read individual characters from a file into an array

Tags: arrays, c, file

Newbie here. I need to create a program that reads strings from a textfile.txt then processes a few characters from it.

The contents of textfile.txt is as below.

```
JA100200300 
FE111222333
MA101202303
```

I need to reference "JA","100", "200" and "300" separately. I managed to do this with the code below, where I split the string into 11 characters and put it into array. Of course this code works only as you type out the string. I need a way to do the same thing but get the string from a file instead.

```
while((a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 11);
```

How do I do this? Can I read the file and put each line of string into an array, then read from the array and split each array into multiple arrays? Is that possible? Or read each character from the file and put them into arrays something like `fscanf %d` but split each character?

Comment: You are looking for `fopen`, `fclose` and `fgetc`. `fgets` might also be useful, it allows you to read an entire line into a char buffer.

Comment: Try reading a _line_ with an ample sized buffer and `fgets()`, then `sscanf()` with `"%2s3d%3d%3d"`.

Comment: You need a basic file I/O tutorial, and SO is not the right site for that. Keep reading the textbook, or use Google instead!

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
FILE fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
char line[100] = { 0 }, str1[3], str2[4], str3[4], str4[4];

if (!fp) {
    perror("opening file");
    exit(1);
}

while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fp)) {
    strncpy(str1,line,2);
    str1[2] = '\0';
    strncpy(str2,&line[2],3);
    str2[3] = '\0';
    strncpy(str3,&line[5],3);
    str3[3] = '\0';
    strncpy(str4,&line[8],3);
    str4[3] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: When I try to print str1, str2, str3, str4 the output is "MAMA1MA1MA1". I tried to edit the code and it just won't give me the results I need. Can you help modify it?

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. See correction above.

Comment: It seems to be getting the last line of the file only, which is MA101202303.  How do I reference each line? Once  have that then I'll use for loop.

Comment: You will have to make `str1`, `str2`, `str3`, and `str4` into arrays of strings to save them all. I was just showing you how to read them in.